# Compile with Visual Studio Shell (Isolated) 2015

Tags: c++, compilation, visual-studio-shell

It is possible to use the compile command (`cl` and `link`) in **`Command Prompt`** if I only installed the VS Shell (isolated) which is part of the **`Atmel Studio`**?

Neither **`Command Prompt`** nor **`Power Shell`** know the `cl command`!

Edit :I searched for cl.exe and the developer promt but didn't found it.

Edit : downloaded visual studio tools but still can not find the developer promt :(

Unfortunately I can't install the full visual studio version.

Comment: You probably don't have the native `c++` compiler installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Developer Command Prompt for **VS 2015** installed, you can.
 Essentially, it's an application that opens a `command prompt` inside the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2015\VERSION`, where `VERSION` will depend on which edition of **Visual Studio** you have installed (Community, Professional, or Enterprise).

Otherwise you could `cd` into the folder where the compiler executable is and run it by typing its name, passing it parameters and pressing Enter, or you could add the path to it to your [PATH environment variable](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) (although I haven't tried this personally and can't vouch on how well this will work).